# В Spring приложении не работают методы PATCH/DELETE (PUT?)

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

В `Spring` приложении (`java`) адекватно работали все контроллеры (взятие\добавление\изменение\удаление , т.е. `GET` \ `POST` \ `PATCH` \ `DELETE` реквесты), однако после добавления зависимости `Spring Security` в какой-то момент перестали работать методы `DELETE` и `PATCH`. При этом методы `GET` \ `POST` работают исправно для всех контроллеров. При попытке обращения к методам `PATCH` \ `DELETE` в консоли выдает следующую ошибку:

```
WARN 15516 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported]
```

В это время на самой ссылке по этому запросу выдает следующий результат

[image: сообщение при попытке перехода в браузере]

Если это важно могу скинуть код перезаписанного метода `configure(HttpSecurity http)`. Также возможно важно, контроллеры реализованы с помощью аннотаций `@Controller`, а не `@RestController`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?
P.S. конфигурация Spring Security выглядит следующим образом:
https://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/3vl8 (по ссылке, чтобы не засорять вопрос)

Comment: Приложите к вопросу конфигурацию `Spring Security`

Comment: 1. попробуйте сделать аннотацию RestController. 2. Передавайте нужные заголовок в Content-Type, которым помечены у вас методы PATCH/DELETE (скорее всего, надо передавать application-json)

Comment: @Alexandr Приложил конфигурацию (если я правильно понял, если нужно что-то еще, то скажите)

Answer (score 1):

У вас написано, что по такому адресу нет метода, который мог бы обработать запрос, а именно - POST(тоесть @PostMapping метод в контроллере). Проверьте, все ли вы корректно вводите в адресной строке (может, вы не тот метод http использовали, забыли приставку добавить context-path). Spring security тут не при чем, скорее всего

Comment: Однако PostMapping и GetMapping аннотации работают для всех контроллеров, в отличие от DeleteMapping и PatchMapping, которые и вызывают эту ошибку (см. WARN... в вопросе). Поясните, пожалуйста, что за context-path приставка и куда ее надо добавить (если можно, как можно подробнее)

Answer (score 1):

Я нашел решение проблемы, оно заключалось в том, что до запуска Spring Security я запускал приложение с помощью Tomcat Server, когда в данный момент для запуска я использую класс с Аннотацией @SpringBootApplication, который использует свою конфигурацию, отличную от конфигурации Tomcat сервера (для этого был создан другой класс мною же). Так вот решил я проблему простым добавлением бина

```
@Bean
    HiddenHttpMethodFilter hiddenHttpMethodFilter() {
        return new HiddenHttpMethodFilter();
    }
```

в мой класс с аннотацией @SpringBootApplication. После этого все неработающие методы (DELETE,PATCH) заработали.